# how to access this complex dictionary list elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
result={"message":"Error logging in for user sana123@gmail.com","status":"Error: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=xxxx] {\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"EMAIL_NOT_FOUND\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n      
  \"message\": \"EMAIL_NOT_FOUND\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"invalid\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n"}
```

for accessing value of "message" key, we will use :

```
result['message']
```

But how do I access :

1. "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND"
2. "reason": "invalid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of `result["status"]` is Json encoded message. To decode it, first remove the `Errno:` part and then use `json.loads`. For example:

```py
import json

result = {
    "message": "Error logging in for user sana123@gmail.com",
    "status": 'Error: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=xxxx] {\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n      "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "invalid"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n',
}

data = json.loads("{" + result["status"].split("] {", maxsplit=1)[-1])
for error in data["error"]["errors"]:
    print(error["message"])
    print(error["reason"])
```

Prints:

```
EMAIL_NOT_FOUND
invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

`result['message']` contains text and a JSON string, you first need to extract the JSON part, then to parse the string (with native library `json`).

```
import json
json_string = result['status'][result['status'].find('{'):]
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Then `data` will be the following `dict`.

```
{'error': {'code': 400,
  'message': 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND',
  'errors': [{'message': 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND',
    'domain': 'global',
    'reason': 'invalid'}]}}
```